# How to translate "Summoners War"?

Tags: traduction

I was wondering what was the best translation of "Summoners War" (which is the name a rather famous mobile game).
I was thinking about "Guerre des invocateurs" but the missing apostrophe ( (why "Summoners War" and not "Summoners' War" or even "War of Summoners") raises me a doubt.

What do you think about it?

Comment: Which apostrophe are you talking about? The translation you propose seems ok although I must admit it sounds a bit strange, probably due to the fact that the term "invocateur" is used in very specific contexts, so not that often.

Comment: Because I was thinking about "Summoners' War" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Summon* dans le sens d'appeler et faire apparaître par la magie, c'est *évoquer*, pas *invoquer*.  Le Robert définit *évoquer* comme suit, c'est le premier sens qu'il donne au mot :

- appeler, faire apparaître par la magie.
  *évoquer les âmes des morts, les démons, les esprits.  Formule, sortilège servant à évoquer les démons*

*Invoquer*, c'est appeler à l'aide par la prière (Le Robert), sans donc l'élément d'apparition qui caractérise l'évocation. Si on tient à traduire strictement le titre du jeu, c'est plutôt de *La guerre des évocateurs* qu'il s'agit.  Quant à l'absence d'apostrophe, je la vois comme une licence qu'ont prise les créateurs du jeu.

Comment: *Évoquer* a perdu ce sens aujourd'hui. *To summon*, ce peut être aussi *convoquer* mais ni *convoquer* (donner l'ordre de venir), ni *évoquer* (se remémorer, faire allusion) ne fonctionnent bien dans ce contexte alors qu' *invoquer* (faire appel par la prière) apporte le côté "magie noire" qui convient mieux à ce jeu. Comparer : "il convoque les dieux", "il évoque les dieux" et "il invoque les dieux".

Comment: @jlliagre  Je ne crois pas que le sens soit perdu.  J'ai cité le Littré par flemme pcq il est en ligne.  Le Robert ne le donne ni pour archaïque ni pour vieilli.  J'amende mon post pour reprendre la définition du Robert.

Comment: Le TLFI le considérait déjà comme "vieux" il y 30 ou 40 ans: *1. Vx. Appeler, faire apparaître par la magie. Évoquer les ombres, les morts. Évoquer les esprits, les démons (Ac.). Et, redressant ses poils raides comme des clous, Il évoque, en hurlant, l'âme des anciens loups (Leconte de Lisle, Poèmes trag.,1886, p. 69):*

Comment: La plupart de la littérature fantastique et des jeux de rôles actuels utilisent Invocateur ou conjurateur. Les écoles de magie d'"évocation" sont plus du domaine physique que l'"invocation" qui fera apparaître des créatures.

Comment: @jlliagre  Intéressant, le Robert que je cite est Le Nouveau Petit Robert (1993), je n'ai pas d'édition plus récente sous la main.  Je trouve dommage de renoncer à la différence entre "évoquer Satan" avec nuage de fumée et odeur de soufre et "invoquer Satan", dire simplement son nom pour demander son aide sans qu'il n'apparaisse.  Mais je suis peut-être un peu old school.

Comment: @MakorDal  Merci de ces précisions, je connais mal les usages lexicaux en cours dans les jeux de rôle et la littérature fantastique actuelle.

Answer (score 4):

You can translate it by : **La guerre des Invocateurs**. Summoners are often relative to a person who practices evocation, by calling upon or summoning a spirit or deity. 
 [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summoner)

Moreover, we often use *Summoner* as **Invocateur**. Indeed, in *League of Legends*, a summoner spell is translated by : **Sorts d'invocateur** and a summoner is a mob who can summon other mobs to his aid in *World Of Warcraft* also translated as **Invocateur**.

Comment: Thank you but the question was less about the word "Summoners" than the grammatical structure, please see my comment to the main question.

Comment: @Blincer This reply perfectly answer your question, if not, please edit your post to add more details.

Comment: Not really, I mention the apostrophe as the central point of my doubt (why Summoners War and not Summoners' War) whereas your answer doesn't even include any note about it.

Comment: @Blincer Wouldn't the reason for/correctness of the lack of an apostrophe in the game's English name need to be determined first/elsewhere in order to get a definite, unconditional answer here (ie: one that doesn't require "pleading in the alternative")? That said, in view of how "de" is used in French to mark possession, I think this answer would be correct regardless of whether there should be an apostrophe in English. (Except in the unlikely event that "war" is meant to be a verb in the English name="[The] Summoners Engage in War," in which case "Les Invocateurs Font La Guerre" might work).

Comment: Given that Summoners is not an adjective, I guess considering war as a verb is the way to go, thank you

Comment: Get a look at Pathfinder and Dungeon and Dragon translation, it could also improve your answer.